# Stalled or nonexistent Netlify serverless function response

Tags: javascript, vite, serverless, netlify, preact

My serverless function will occasionally respond after a long delay, 14-30s, but most often it simply stalls without responding. This occurred soon after transferring my syntax from CommonJS to ESModules.

[image: no response from serverless function]

In my browser's network tab, the request is stuck on the Initial Connection phase:

[image: request stuck on the initial connectin phase]

I have tried configuring my Netlify.toml file to use the esbuild node bundler, and defined my imports (jsonwebtoken, mongodb & bcrypt) as external node modules. As stated previously, this initially made the function run again, but it soon stalled again. After stalling, none of the code inside the function file (auth.js) will run, even if I edit it into a boilerplate handler export:

```
export const handler = async function(event, context) {
   console.log('never runs')
   return { statusCode: 400 }
}
```

I have another serverless function that seems to run just fine; it's mainly this function that is the issue.

auth.js (located at netlify/functions/auth/auth.js):

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'
import { mongoConfig } from '../config'

const { URI, DATABASE, USER_COLLECTION, SESSION_SECRET } = process.env,
  clientPromise = new MongoClient(URI, mongoConfig)

export const handler = async function (event, context) {
  const { httpMethod } = event,
    { username, password } = JSON.parse(event.body)

  if (httpMethod !== 'POST')
    return {
      statusCode: 404,
      body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'not found' }),
    }

  if (!username || !password)
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'missing username or password fields' }),
    }

  try {
    const database = (await clientPromise).db(DATABASE),
      collection = database.collection(USER_COLLECTION),
      adminUser = await collection.findOne({ username })

    await clientPromise.close()

    const bcrypt = await import('bcrypt')
    if (adminUser === null || !bcrypt.compareSync(password, adminUser.password))
      return {
        statusCode: 401,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          error: 'incorrect username or password',
        }),
      }

    const jwt = await import('jsonwebtoken'),
      token = jwt.sign(
        {
          username,
        },
        SESSION_SECRET,
        {
          expiresIn: '24h',
        }
      )

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'set-cookie': `jwt=${token}; secure; httpOnly; sameSite=Lax`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username,
        token,
      }),
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)

    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        serverError: error.toString(),
      }),
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: What whenever the auth function does respond, often after I restart the server, this is the received response:
[image: server error response]

[image: server error log]

If I try to go into auth.js and add a log after dynamically importing JWT, then reload localhost, I'm back to the previously described stalled behaviour.